# How to estimate a failure probability?

Tags: probability, modeling, algorithms

I am trying to come up with an approximate formula for the failure probability of an event which can be caused by four factors: vendor, distance, continent, and configuration. I have over 100 observations. The outcome is measured as a proportion of failures. Vendor has five levels, distance is a continuous measure in kilometers, and configuration has three levels.

I would like to develop a formula that would predict failure as a function of the four factors.

Comment: Do you have the given failure probability or only observed failures, i.e. is your response variable binary or continuous?

Comment: How is the failure probability obtained/calculated?

Comment: The probability I have is observed failure rates. It is just empirical data.

Comment: @Eric is it failure within a specified time period? Do you know how many objects/people/whatever were at risk? e.g. do you know 46% or do you know it was 23 deaths out of 50 at risk? Are you familiar with binomial/logistic regression?